# Steady state , Ohms law, Inductor circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

$B_{\phi} = LI$

$\frac{\partial B_{\phi}}{\partial t} = L \frac{dI}{dt}$

$\epsilon = -L \frac{dI}{dt}$

Now, Let's say that my circuit has a battery, a wire  and a certain inductance.

The battery has a some potential difference $V_{0} $

Applying faradays law to the  circuit

$\int E \cdot dl = \frac{\partial B_{\phi}}{\partial t}$

going in the direction of my current, I would get

$-V_{0} + IR =  -L \frac{dI}{dt}$

Now, this is the equation that supposedly governs my circuit

How is this equation true?

As, V=IR is valid only for steady state, and is derived under the assumption that acceleration is zero.Meaning if di/dt is non zero this equation is invalid.

applying this equation properly, Using ohms law would require that di/dt is zero

Giving

$-V_{0} + IR = 0$

$V_{0} = IR$

Any thoughts on this?

Even so, Given this is "approximately true"

It can be rearranged to give

$V_{0}  -L \frac{dI}{dt} = IR$

This has the physical interpretation of

IR being the total potential difference across the wires, due to the batteries potential added with an opposing potential being induced.

This is basically an " equation of motion" in terms of work, where IR could be synonymous  with "ma"

Aka the net potential in the wire.

So when the resistance is zero, This equation has the physical interpretation of there being a net zero electric field inside my wire

, If there is a net zero electric field inside my wire, then intuitively I would say there will be no changing current

setting r = 0
gives

$V_{0}  = L \frac{dI}{dt}$

Solving this equation

Gives me VT/L = I

Which definitely produces a changing current. Surely this is, atleast on the surface paradoxical given the physical interpretation above ( being net zero E field in the wire)

Well intuitively also I would reason that when the applied voltage equals induced voltage ,there is a constant velocity, meaning di/dt is zero meaning no opposing emfz meaning a there IS a force on the charge meaning di/dt ISNT ZERO meaning constant velocity and there goes an infinite loop

(But even so this equation is technically invalid as di/dt should.he zero if I'm using ohms law, which actually should give me v=0) Using the non steady state version of ohms law will give me a non zero net emf when resistance is 0 and intuitively makes sense.

Main question then, is that why are we using ohms law when it's not valid, and if the equations say that the emfs are balanced, how.can there be a changing current ( and IS this "paradox" caused by a steady state approximation as in reality even jf r =0 there is still an E field

Answer (score 0):

Ohm's law gives a relationship between an instantaneous current through a conductor (resistor) and an instantaneous voltage drop across the conductor. The *instantaneous* is key to understand, i.e. the Ohm's law always applies to resistors!

Steady state does not mean DC value, it only implies that some variable (or variables) does not change. Instead of a battery, imagine you connect a sine-wave voltage source to your system. The current will not be ideal sine wave right from the beginning. It will take some time for system to go through the *transient state* after which it enters *steady state*. Is the current zero in this case? Certainly not, in steady state it will be a perfect sine wave with constant amplitude. Steady state in this case means the amplitude and phase do not change.

Now let's go back to the example with the battery. The equation you mentioned also always applies. When you first connect the battery, it will take some time to *build up* current through the inductor. During this time $\frac{d}{dt}i(t) \neq 0$, but at some point when the current reaches it final value $V/R$, it stops increasing which means all the (battery) voltage is across the resistor. This is called **steady state**. If you suddenly short the battery, the energy stored in the inductor's magnetic field starts inducing voltage in the inductor and current starts gradually decreasing until it reaches zero.

---

> Solving this equation gives me VT/L=I

This is correct, but it seems to me you assume T is constant. It is not.

$$V_0 = L \frac{d}{dt}i(t) \quad \longrightarrow \quad i(t) = \frac{V_0}{L} \cdot t + i(0)$$

where $t$ only increases. This means the current goes to infinity as time goes to infinity.

With resistor in the circuit, the equation is

$$V_0 = i(t) R + L \frac{d}{dt} i(t)$$

Assuming $V_0$ is constant, solving the above differential equation gives expression for current:

$$i(t) = \frac{V_0}{R} \left( 1 - e^{-t/\tau} \right), \qquad \tau = \frac{L}{R}$$

Now as time goes to infinity, the final current goes to $\frac{V_0}{R}$. In electrical engineering, we say it takes $5\tau$ to reach stedy state, at which point current is at 99.33% of the final value.

Comment: Ohms law  doesn't always apply...  The derivation of ohms law assumes the resistive forces are equal to the applied potential from the battery. Ohms law states the potential required to maintain a constant current after the transients have died down. If I apply a voltage to a circuit, The current doesn't immediately go to V/R. Ohms law applies when t -> infinity .I can intuitively understand the equation for an LR circuit when resistance is non zero. The steady state I am talking about isn't the steady state with inductance, it is steady state in ohms law itself.When r=0 -

Comment: the current increases linearly with time, however the equation seems to also say the net emf in the wire is zero, which would imply a constant current.

Comment: I understand t increases, and so current jncreases linearly. However IR is the net potential in the wire , if the net potential is zero  then how can there be an acceleration?

Comment: I will be more precise - Ohm's law always applies to resistive elements. There is no such thing as *"steady state in Ohm's law"* because Ohm's law applies to instantaneous values. In case when resistance is zero, the net potential of the inductor equals battery voltage due to which current increases to infinity. This is an example of an *unstable system*, which does not have steady state.

Comment: Do you know the derivation of ohms law? If so, it is clear that it is the steady state of the differential equation ma= qE - m/T v This is the drude model of conductivity. Ohms law clearly Is steady state. set a to be equal to zero and you get J = $\sigma$ E which is the steady state solution. You may want to familiarise your self with the full solution to the differential equation above

Comment: And if the net potential of the inductor equals the applied voltage, the net EMF  is zero. meaning no acceleration?

Comment: Ohms law is also completely invalid altogether with sinusoidal frequencies. with the introduction to the complex conductivity.

Comment: Maybe you are onto something, but honestly, from your question and from your comments I cannot understand what you are trying to say. I hope someone else provides better answer. I did not downvote your question, so I have a feeling someone else feels the same about how the question was formulated.

Answer (score 0):

> This is basically an " equation of motion" in terms of work, where IR
> could be synonymous with "ma"

Not quite. The electro-mechanical analogy is velocity = current, mass = inductance, and force = voltage.

So, the situation without resistance
$$V_0 = L\frac{dI}{dt}$$  is equivalent to $F = ma$. The current will grow unbounded if there is no resistance and there is an applied voltage.

Comment: Mathematically I can solve the equation. However intuitively. If IR represents the potential difference across my wire.  if this is set to zero, Then how can there be a changing current? because if the potential difference across the wire is zero then there is no force acting on the electrons

Comment: IR is the potential difference for a constant current. But is is not a general expression. If there is a changing current there is an emf in the wire even for zero resistance. It is like a force applied in a body without any friction. The force is not balanced by a friction force. But it doesn't vanish. There is a force and an acceleration.

Comment: My question is, is  $V_{0}$ + (-L Di/dt) the net emf? if it  is Net emf  then this is defined to be zero , thus no force on charges. the equation seems to suggest the emfs are balanced? what aren't I doing correct

Comment: No. The differential equation is: $L\frac{dI}{dt} + RI = V_0$. If $L<<R$ we have simply the Ohm's law. If $R = 0$ we have a linearly growing current.